# Socket io not working under Express project on heroku

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, express, io

the contents of my app.js

```
  var express =require('express'),
    app =express();
    server=require('http').createServer(app),
    io =require ('socket.io').listen(server);
    io.configure(function () { 
        io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
        io.set("polling duration", 10); 
        }); 
    users = {};
    var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    server.listen(port);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


    io.set('log level',1);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log("hey");
    socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
        if (data in users){
            console.log("hey");
            callback(false);
        } else{
            callback(true);
            console.log("hey1");
            socket.nickname = data;
            users[socket.nickname] = socket;
            updateNicknames();
        }
    });
.
.
.
.
```

in public/index.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var socket = io.connect();
.
.
```

the index.html gets loaded up ... typically mine app is a basic chat app 
url is http://chat-up.herokuapp.com/

so the first step is to get a user name and the check if the username is already taken but

the url changes from http://chat-up.herokuapp.com/ to http://chat-up.herokuapp.com/?

my guess is that the sockets aren't working

what am i doing wrong or is there any way to do this ?

thank you

Comment: You may need to give the an URL to your client lib : `var socket = io.connect('http://chat-up.herokuapp.com/');`

Comment: @krampstudio even tried that didnt work